# Get http session / request in hibernate interceptor

Tags: spring, hibernate, servlets

I want to to implement an audit logging module to my existing system and I want to save actual logged user information and it's only the httpSession.

I'm using hibernate/spring/struts 2, and in order to get actual logged user information and call saveLog service I need the ServletContext to find those service bean or get the httpServletRequest...

I have been searching and seems binding the session to ThreadLocal usign Filter is the only way? [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423924/how-to-get-hibernate-session-inside-a-hibernate-interceptor)  or [this (last answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866728/get-httpsessionrequest-from-simple-java-class-not-servlet-class)

is there other suggestion? is this a commun pattern or a good practice  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring can bind current request to the thread out of the box. If you use `DispatcherServlet`, it's done automatically, otherwise you need to declare [`RequestContextFilter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/RequestContextFilter.html).

Then you can access request properties via [`RequestContextHolder`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of Hibernate, you may be able to use [Envers](http://www.jboss.org/envers) to accommodate fine-grained audit logging.  This includes the ability to add the 'current user' from a session variable into the given Revision:

```
@Entity
@RevisionEntity(ExampleListener.class)
public class ExampleRevEntity extends DefaultRevisionEntity {
    private String username;

    public String getUsername() { return username; }
    public void setUsername(String username) { this.username = username; }
}
```

This integrates with Hibernate nicely through a series of eventListeners, which you can call out in Spring like so:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
...
    <property name="eventListeners">
        <map>
            <entry key="post-insert" value-ref="enversEventListener"/>
            <entry key="post-update" value-ref="enversEventListener"/>
            <entry key="post-delete" value-ref="enversEventListener"/>
            <entry key="pre-collection-update" value-ref="enversEventListener"/>
            <entry key="pre-collection-remove" value-ref="enversEventListener"/>
            <entry key="post-collection-recreate" value-ref="enversEventListener"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Then you can query for audit revisions through the Envers query api.

After using this on a couple of recent projects, it's my preferred audit technique when using Hibernate.

To answer your question, you can then setup a Hibernate Interceptor or Envers RevisionListener to access the 'current user' by looking it up from the current Spring context:

```
applicationContext.getBean("currentUser", User.class);
```

as long as your user is setup as a scoped bean in Spring.

Comment: I have been looking into Envers, but as far as I know it will have to create 2 tables for every entity and that's not what I want. I would like the audit log save into only one table.

Comment: Saving into multiple tables (1 for audited entities, 1 for audit history and 1 for central revision ticket), for us, had a bunch of advantages.  Keeping the audit history out of the live entities is a performance aid and helps keep your domain and controller code properly segmented: separating history from actual records.

Answer (score 0):

There was this article [how to implement the Hibernate Listener as Spring bean](http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-managed-hibernate) to have full access to the Spring Context.

This may open complete new ways in your scenario (Depending on your app).

Answer (score 0):

Example for spring boot (spring-boot-starter 1.2.4.RELEASE).

In some controller:

```
@RequestMapping("login")
public UserBean login(@RequestParam("email") String email,
                      @RequestParam("password") String password,
                      HttpSession session) {
    // getting usser
    session.setAttribute("currentUser", user);
    return user;
}
```

Register hibernate listeners

```
import org.hibernate.event.service.spi.EventListenerRegistry;
import org.hibernate.event.spi.*;
import org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl;
import org.hibernate.jpa.HibernateEntityManagerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

@Component
public class UiDateListener implements PostLoadEventListener, PreUpdateEventListener {
    @Inject EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        HibernateEntityManagerFactory hibernateEntityManagerFactory = (HibernateEntityManagerFactory) this.entityManagerFactory;
        SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactoryImpl = (SessionFactoryImpl) hibernateEntityManagerFactory.getSessionFactory();
        EventListenerRegistry registry = sessionFactoryImpl.getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
        registry.appendListeners(EventType.POST_LOAD, this);
        registry.appendListeners(EventType.PRE_UPDATE, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostLoad(PostLoadEvent event) {
        final Object entity = event.getEntity();
        if (entity == null) return;

        final UserBean currentUser = (UserBean) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getAttribute("currentUser", RequestAttributes.SCOPE_SESSION);
        // some logic after entity loaded
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent event) {
        final Object entity = event.getEntity();
        if (entity == null) return false;

        // some logic before entity persist

        return false;
    }
}
```